# splitting a string into words and punctuation without using any import

Tags: python, string, punctuation

I've seen similar questions to my question, but they all used regex.What I want to do is taking input such as "Wow,this was really helpfull!" and return to "Wow , this was really helpfull ! " So i want to split punctuations from words.And I have tried this one but it does not working at all:

```
sentence = input()
punctuation = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~"
    for punc in sentence :

    if punc in punctuation :
        outputpunc = " %s" % punc
    else :

      outputpunc = character
    separatedPunctuation += outputpunc
print separatedPunctuation.split()
```

Comment: It is not quite clear what inputs you may get. Does https://ideone.com/zcE98k work for you?

Comment: Thank you ,it is want I want but I also want to  split words into parts and I am not sure that is also possible to do it in that way.

Comment: Yes, see https://ideone.com/VFytlA

Comment: Oh thank you, what I want to say was, is it possible to split 'helpful' to 'help ful' or any suffix from words?

Comment: You probably need some morphosyntactic parser. Or use subword generation software, like BPE and SentencePiece.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is not 100% clear as in if you want a second space after a punctuation if two appear right after another.

But assuming you are fine with two spaces, the code could look something like this:

```
sentence_in = "Wow,this was really helpful!"
sentence_out = ""
punctuation = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~"

for character in sentence_in:

    if character in punctuation:
        sentence_out += " %s " % character
    else:
        sentence_out += character

print(sentence_out)
```

The problem with your code is that it is not correctly indented which is important in Python since it is used to indicate a code block.
For example see:

```
for punc in sentence :

if punc in punctuation :
    outputpunc = " %s" % punc
else :

    outputpunc = character
```

Should really look like this:

```
for punc in sentence :
    if punc in punctuation :
        outputpunc = " %s" % punc
    else :
        outputpunc = character
```

As you can see the rest of the code after the beginning of the for-loop needs to be indented. After you are finished with your loop you can go back to the same level of indentation as before.